# Complete seperation of frontend and backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, model-view-controller

I have decided to add a new developer to a Rails project I am hosting on GitHub. He has a good understanding of UI(JS, CSS, HTML) and good taste for UX. 
The problem is I don't want him to go through the trouble of figuring out Ajax calls and responses coming from the backend and figuring out how to set up and configure Rails on his local system.

Essentially I am looking for a tool/IDE that:
 
1- Pulls the GitHub code 
2- Slices the V out of MVC 
3- Allows me to plug in the response data he will need to independently work on the UI 
4- Push code back to GitHub.

Of course 1 and 4 are just for convenience and not necessary.
Any ideas will be appreciated :)

Comment: Don't think that's gona happen. Rails has a powerful assets pipeline build in, which cannot be ignored when working with front end and it requires ruby. Installing ruby is very easy, installing gems - also easy. You can save him some time setting him up with sqlite, so no db instalation is needed. If you want a real forntend-backend separation, you should write a separate rails-api application and frontend app.

Comment: Agreed with BroiSatse. If you already have an existing Rails app and you want to stand up endpoints to hook into rather quickly, I would just use something like Grape to make those endpoints. You can use grape_swagger_rails to get a UI to test those endpoints. I did this when building an Angular app mounted on top of Rails.